# Need to write JUnit test for Scala code

Tags: java, scala, junit

I am new to Scala and Spark. I need to write JUnit for the following word count program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark._

object SparkWordCount {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    meth()

  }

  def meth() {

    //Spark Config object having cluster information
    val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("SparkWordCount")
      .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)

    val input = sc.textFile("C:\\SparkW\\input\\inp.txt")
    val count = input.flatMap(line ⇒ line.split(" "))
      .map(word ⇒ (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    count.saveAsTextFile("outfile")
    System.out.println("OK");

  }

}
```

How do I write a test for this using JUnit?

Comment: What have you tried first after having a look at the Spark doc to see how it should be tested?

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... **you** start by putting your thoughts / current code; and we help with solving issues. We dont do that first step for you.

Comment: If you are familiar with Java, you can test your Scala code from Java, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the many scala spec/test libraries

a test can look like

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class WordCountSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "wordCount" should "return an empty output for an empty input" in
withLocalSparkContext { context =>
  val lines = context.emptyRDD[String]
  val words = WordCount.wordCount(lines).collect()
  words should be (Seq.empty)
}}
```

check this for a full example [Spec Class](https://github.com/greyamigo/spark-plug/blob/master/test/scala/WordCountSpec.scala)

there are example programs out there for scalatest specification etc, have a search around

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I also found another solution,so thought of sharing it

import java.io.File

import org.junit.{Assert, Test}

/**
  * Created by usharani on 07-07-2017.
  */
class SparkWordCountTest {

@Test
  def test(): Unit = {
    val line1 = new File("outfile/part-00000")
    val line2 = new File("C:/Users/usharani/IdeaProjects/Practice/src/test/scala/inputs.txt")
    val myString = scala.io.Source.fromFile(line1).getLines.mkString
    val myString1 = scala.io.Source.fromFile(line2).getLines.mkString
    println(myString)
    println(myString1)
    Assert.assertEquals(myString, myString1)

}
}